# update picklist value using process builder

Tags: workflow, administration, formula-field, process-builder

I have a object called job application and another object called Interview. On interview I have a lookup relationship field to the job application object.

I have a picklist field called status in job application. I have a pick list field called recommendation in Interview. I would like to update the status on job application based on the recommendation field. I was thinking to use cross object update but it only works in Master-detail relationship. How can I achieve this? Is it possible through process builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can update related records in Process Builder.

Select Interview as object node and select criteria node based on recommendation field.

[image]

Then create a immediate action as update records and select Job Application. There you can set the status field based on the criteria node (based on recommendation).

You you create each criteria node for each value in recommendation field in Interview object.

Hope is helps.

Comment: If recommendation is a picklist value, how do I create the criteria condition? I would like the criteria be if recommendation == 'Reject'

Comment: When I use - [Interview__c].Recommendations__c == 'Reject' I get an error - The formula expression is invalid: Field Interview is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

Comment: Got it now. I used the option - "Conditions are met"

Comment: Added a sample screenshot for the criteria node selection. Take a look.